# Registering .dlls remotely using PsExec and RegSvcs.exe from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, registration, psexec

I'm trying to register .dlls on a remote server using PsExec from a PowerShell script.

My script looks like this:

```
ForEach($component in $registerComponents) {
    try {
        PsExec "\\$targetServer" -u $userName -p $password C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegSvcs.exe /u /nologo "$component.dll"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $Error
    }
}
```

Each time I run the script, it will progress one component further than the last before hanging i.e. the first time I run it, it will successfully unregister the first $component and hang on the second; the second time, the first and second components will get unregistered before hanging on the third.

Thinking that the RegSvcs.exe process may still be running on the remote server and that this could be the cause, I added a PsKill call as follows:

```
ForEach($component in $registerComponents) {
    try {
        PsExec "\\$targetServer" -u $userName -p $password C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegSvcs.exe /u /nologo "$component.dll"
        PsKill "\\$targetServer" -u $userName -p $password RegSvcs.exe
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $Error
    }
}
```

... but to no avail. From remote login on the server, taskmanager will show RegSvcs.exe when it is running; when the script hangs, it appears the process is not being executed.

This seems like it should work OK but I haven't been able to make it so.
Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: is there some reason that you're using RegSvcs.exe instead of Regsvr32.exe?

Comment: To register these types as COM+...